# I've declared variable "x" but i did not call it, is it ok to not call variables that have values assigned?

Tags: python, list, function, random, addition

```
import random


def add_sums(Num):
    total = 0
    all_num = []
    for x in range(1, Num+1):
        gen = random.randint(1, 30)
        all_num.append(gen)
    
    print("List:", all_num)
    for y in all_num:
        total += y
    print("List total:", total)


user_max = int(input("Max numbers in list: "))
add_sums(user_max)
```

In this program, the user will enter the total amount of numbers in a list.
the `random` module will generate random numbers between `1` to `30`.
Then all the numbers from the list will be added together.

I've tried to use the variable `x` but it doesn't give the results I want, does anyone know a better/simpler way of creating this program. Also, is it bad practice to create a variable and not call it?

Comment: Small hint: You don't have to add up the values for `total` manually. A simple `total = sum(all_num)` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Maybe this better/simpler way of creating this program

```
import random

def add_sums(Num):

    all_num = []
    for x in range(Num):
        all_num.append(random.randint(1, 30))
    print("List:", all_num)
    print("List total:", sum(all_num))
user_max = int(input("Max numbers in list: "))

add_sums(user_max)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, I didn't know that you could use the random method inside the append method :D,

Answer (score 2):

When you're iterating through a list but don't need the index, it's common to use an underscore to indicate the index isn't used.

```
for _ in range(1, Num+1):
    gen = random.randint(1, 30)
    all_num.append(gen)
```

Comment: With a list comprehension this boils down to `all_num = [random.randint(1, 30) for _ in range(Num)]`.

Comment: Thank you, so if I want to create a variable but I do not want to call it, I will just use _.